# How to force line-break when screen width changes using css

Tags: css, sass

In my code, I have a 2 lined text. I want to move the second text (nth-child(3): 10 x apples) to the line below when the width of the screen changes. I have tried `display:block` and `white-space:pre`. But it didn't work and the sentence did not move to next line. My code and a screenshot is below. What should I do to achieve this?

```
@media (min-width: breakpoint-max(sm)) {
  .fruit-detail {
    & :nth-child(3) {
        display: block;
    }
  }
}

<div class="fruit-detail">
    <span class="day-one ng-star-inserted">
        "Yesterday"
    </span>
    <span class="ng-star-inserted">
        Today
    </span>
    <span> 10 x </span>
    <span>Apples</span>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap "10 x Apples" around a parent container and give it:

```
    .parentContainer::after{
        content: "\a";
        white-space: pre;
    }
```

Don't know if it works tho, though I don't have sass installed.
This is just a suggestion because it worked for me :).

Comment: Upvoted for the line break, but you don't need to wrap elements here

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle the visibility for a break tag by providing a class to it and setting `display:none;` to it in your main css and `display: block` in your matching media query.

Refer to this for a practical example : https://codepen.io/darshiljani/pen/QWxdqpz

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the third `.fruit-detail`.

I don't think you can use `display:block` here because "10x" and "Apples" won't be side by side.

You can select the second span and add a line break with `:after` (or the third with `:before`)

```css
.fruit-detail:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: orange;
}

.fruit-detail span:nth-child(2):after {
  content: "\a";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="fruit-detail">
  <span>"Yesterday"</span>
  <span>Today</span>
  <span> 10 x </span>
  <span>Apples</span>
</div>

<div class="fruit-detail">
  <span>"Yesterday"</span>
  <span>Today</span>
  <span> 10 x </span>
  <span>Strawberries</span>
</div>

<div class="fruit-detail">
  <span>"Yesterday"</span>
  <span>Today</span>
  <span> 10 x </span>
  <span>Bananas</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but unfortunately, it didn't work with my case

Comment: Is it the result you're looking for ? Can you give more informations to get why it's not working in your case ?

Comment: Okay so in my case, "Today" is the 2nd child, 10 x is the 3rd child and Apples is the 4th child. When I try the solution you have provided, nothing has changed. I don't think he app was affected by it

Comment: So it's the same than the HTML you provided, I made the same snippet using [Sass on codepen](https://codepen.io/cedricbeausseron/pen/GRGNBeJ)

Comment: Did the exact same thing but nope, it looks like no changes have been made.

Comment: Did you check in the devtool if the style is applied but overridden ? Did you re-generate your css file from the sass file ? As you can see it's supposed to work, I can't guess what's your problem